# upgrade nodejs centos 6.9

Tags: node.js, upgrade

I am received this error when try use module nodemailer in nodejs 0.12 distro centos 6.9

/root/node-v0.10.30/node_modules/live_webcam/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:3
const Mailer = require('./mailer');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

I try update in nodejs but yum report 404 package

[yum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc8Kz.jpg)

How to fixed this?

Thank's any Advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The current status of Node 0.12 is End-of-Life which means that you shouldn't expect it to work at all.

See the [Node LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS):

[image]

Few years ago (ages in terms of Node's history) [io.js was forked](http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/nodejs-iojs-why-the-fork/) from Node 0.12 because it was so outdated.

If you don't know how to install a newer version of Node then see [my tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) or [Node website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Comment: Hi thank you so much! After instaling nodejs :

root@sdv7 [/opt/node-6.7.0/node_modules/live_webcam]# node -v
v6.7.0 

I copyed my aplication to /opt/node-6.7.0/node_modules/, but when run node server.js, receive this error : 

root@sdv7 [/opt/node-6.7.0/node_modules/live_webcam]# node server.js
module.js:583
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 14.

Sorry my knowledge is not advanced in nodejs, I need to make some change in the code?

Thank you again!

Comment: Ok, I fixed this change module bcrypt by bryptjs. NodeJs now work for me!

Thank you !